# Confirming AWS SNS Topic Subscription for Slack Webhook

Tags: amazon-web-services, webhooks, amazon-sns, slack, slack-api

I am integrating SNS and Slack. I have created a slack app with incoming webhook enabled. I have got the webhook URL. I created a subscription for a SNS Topic with HTTPS protocol and set the Endpoint the webhookURL. Now the subscription is PendingConfirmation. I didnot receive any confirmation message, not in the destined channel.

How do I confirm the subscription?

Answer (score 53):

You don't need to create a lambda function or create an HTTPS subscription with Slack.

On your slack channel, add the "email integration" app. Once done, Slack will provide you an email address with slack.com domain.

Emails sent to this address will be imported into your slack channel.

Then, on SNS create an email subscription and provide the slack email above.

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @PushpinderSingh, How are you parsing JSON message if you're directly sending message from sns to slack

Comment: This solution worked half-way for me.  I was able to confirm the SNS subscription in slack channel.  But when I publish a message to SNS, the message was not sent to slack.  So I used this solution instead:   [How do I use webhooks to publish Amazon SNS messages to Amazon Chime, Slack, or Microsoft Teams?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-lambda-webhooks-chime-slack-teams/).  This worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 22):

You can confirm the subscription WITHOUT lambda. It is easy.
I found a way to integrate AWS SNS with slack **WITHOUT** `AWS Lambda` or `AWS chatbot`.

Follow the video which show all the step clearly.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CszzQcPAqNM

Steps to follow:

- Create slack channel or use existing channel
- Create a work flow with selecting Webhook
- Create a variable name as `SubscribeURL`. The name is very important
- Add the above variable in the message body of the workflow
- Publish the workflow and get the url
- Add the above Url as subscription of the SNS
- You will see the subscription URL in the slack channel
- Follow the URl and complete the subscription
- Come back to the work flow and change the variable to `Message`
- The publish the message in SNS. you will see the message in the slack channel.

Comment: nice job dude. can confirm it works

Answer (score 9):

The reason you're not seeing it in Slack is because the default [JSON format for SNS messages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-and-json-formats.html#http-notification-json) doesn't conform to the format required by Slack:

> You have two options for sending data to the Webhook URL above:
>
> - Send a JSON string as the payload parameter in a POST request
> - Send a JSON string as the body of a POST request
>
> For a simple message, your JSON payload could contain a text property at minimum. This is the text that will be posted to the channel.

As another user suggested you can use an AWS Lambda function to facilitate this.  There are free, public solutions available already, such as [this one](http://ashiina.github.io/2015/06/cloudwatch-lambda-slack) (which I did not author, and have not used...only including as a reference point).

Answer (score 4):

I might be late on this topic but you can configure AWS Chatbot (slack application) to send all the notifications to your slack.
More info here : https://aws.amazon.com/chatbot/

Comment: This works but Chatbot only accepts messages from specific AWS services and you cannot customize the message which is sent to slack.

Answer (score 3):

You have create a lambda function that receives SNS feedback and POST it to your webhook URL.

When you create a subscription to your lambda topic you choose AWS Lambda as protocol and select the lambda that you just created.

More info about it here: https://medium.com/cohealo-engineering/how-set-up-a-slack-channel-to-be-an-aws-sns-subscriber-63b4d57ad3ea

Comment: This solution is old.  Use this instead: [How do I use webhooks to publish Amazon SNS messages to Amazon Chime, Slack, or Microsoft Teams?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-lambda-webhooks-chime-slack-teams/).  This worked perfectly for me.)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the `SubscribeURL` in a Slack Webhook method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).