# How to confirm a slack subscription to an aws SNS topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, slack, amazon-ses

I have a lambda function that notifies an SNS topic.
It currently sends an email each time I invoke the function so the lambda, the SNS piece and the email subscription are all working ok.

Now I want a Slack Integration.

I've created a channel called `aws_int` but I can't get it to receive the notification.

I am stuck on the need to 'verify the subscription'.  I don't see how I would do this in the https connection to slack.

#### I don't understand how to do it manually using the console in aws because all the documentation keeps referring to using the 'Subscription Confirmation URL'

I can't find what that is.

[image]

[image]

but I cannot find what that is.

I found a post talking about the JSON being invalid: [Confirming AWS SNS Topic Subscription for Slack Webhook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341187/confirming-aws-sns-topic-subscription-for-slack-webhook) but I don't understand how I would use that, maybe I could use Postman but I am not sure exactly how to format that POST.

So how can I integrate Slack and aws for an SNS topic, specifically how can I do the confirmation (which is required in order to activate it).  This has to be a common need!

If I use the hook URL I get

[image]

Everything I am trying is just stacking up more Pending Confirmations, which btw I cannot delete...

[image]

Here's my postman attempt...

[image]

Comment: It might be easier to just call the webhook from the Lambda. The formatting would surely be better too.

Comment: Hmm, yeah but I really want the system decoupled

Comment: and to be able to use these components in many ways and configurations for building applications once I have these sort of building blocks down.  Which I assume will apply to others too for such popular products and what seems like a common and useful integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is a way to confirm an SNS subscription to a Slack endpoint (email, webhook, whatever). If you want to use SNS as a decoupling layer, you'll need to add a lambda into the system, which can handle the confirmation process.

`Lambda -> webhook -> SNS -> Lambda -> webhook -> Slack`

[Confirming AWS SNS Topic Subscription for Slack Webhook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341187/confirming-aws-sns-topic-subscription-for-slack-webhook) has some more information about this.

Answer (score 6):

You really DON'T need Lambda. Just SNS and SLACK are enough.

I found a way to integrate AWS SNS with slack **WITHOUT** `AWS Lambda` or `AWS chatbot`. With this approach you can confirm the subscription easily.

Follow the video which show all the step clearly.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CszzQcPAqNM

Steps to follow:

- Create slack channel or use existing channel
- Create a work flow with  selecting Webhook
- Create a variable name as "SubscribeURL". The name
  is very important
- Add the above variable in the message body of the
  workflow Publish the workflow and get the url
- Add the above Url as subscription of the SNS You will see the subscription URL in the
  slack channel
- Follow the URl and complete the subscription
- Come back to the work flow and change the "SubscribeURL" variable to "Message"
- The publish the
  message in SNS. you will see the message in the slack channel.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just using the Lambda to send a message to slack, either calling another dedicated lambda, or just internally to the original one. There's a good tutorial [here](https://api.slack.com/tutorials/events-api-using-aws-lambda). If you really want to use SNS, then you could use your original lambda to trigger SNS, then have a new slack-dedicated lambda subscribe to the SNS topic.